Swap image on tab selected jQuery
How can I simplify this into one single function:
  $("#tab-one").click(function() {
    var imageUrl = "img/img-1.png";
    $(".masthead.product-detail").css("background-image", "url(" + imageUrl + ")");
  });
  $("#tab-two").click(function() {
    var imageUrl = "img/img-2.png";
    $(".masthead.product-detail").css("background-image", "url(" + imageUrl + ")");
  });
  $("#tab-three").click(function() {
    var imageUrl = "img/img-3.png";
    $(".masthead.product-detail").css("background-image", "url(" + imageUrl + ")");
  });

Many thanks in advance!

Use one click handler for all three, put the image URL to use into a custom data attribute onto each of those individual #tab-xyz elements, and then use https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2 to get the value.

In addition to the linked duplicate there are dozens if not hundreds of similar questions on SO, and there are zillions of jQuery tabs tutorials on the web. I suggest looking into well-established patterns before posting something that's as well-trodden as this is. Also, this is more of an image viewer than tabs. The right search terms get you much closer.

add corresponding image src to each tab as a data-* attribute.
Give a common class to all tabs.
Now you can reduce your code with one click handler like below:
$(".tab").click(function() { // use the common class to apply click handler
 $(".masthead.product-detail").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).data('img-src') + ")");
});

Sample working snippet:


$(".tab").click(function() {
  $(".masthead.product-detail").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).data('img-src') + ")");
});
.product-detail {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;   
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab-one" data-img-src="https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg">Click tab-one</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab-two" data-img-src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/kamchatka/kamchatka1005/kamchatka100500301/6937927-zebras-on-lake.jpg">Click tab-two</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab-three" data-img-src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/painting-mountain-lake-with-mountain-background_188544-9126.jpg">Click tab-three</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="masthead product-detail"> background image will get updated here!</div>




Thanks @Death-is-the-real-truth, works perfect!! Well appreciated.

You can code like this:
In your HTML use data-* attribute:
<div class="tab" id="tab-one" data-image="img/img-1.png">Tab One</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab-two" data-image="img/img-2.png">Tab Two</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab-three" data-image="img/img-3.png">Tab Three</div>

Then in your JavaScript Code:
$(".tab").click(function() {
    var imageUrl = $(this).data("image");
    $(".masthead.product-detail").css("background-image", "url(" + imageUrl + ")");
});

This is how using data-* attribute, simply you can change the background image.

How is this answer different, or adds any more context than the already posted one? Am I missing something obvious?

I didn't see your answer.
